# Getting Error :Column 'people.playerID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting error :

> Column 'people.playerID' is invalid in the select list because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function

```
select 
     p.playerid,NameGiven + ' ( ' + namefirst + ' ) ' + nameLast as [Full Name], 
     teamid, myr,yearid, format(AVG(salary),'C') as [Player Average Salary]
from 
     Salaries s, 
     people p , 
    (select playerid ,max(yearid) as myr 
     from Salaries 
     group by playerID) m
where 
      s.playerID=p.playerID and 
      m.playerID=s.playerID
```

Comment: You're trying to use the AVG function which only works on a set of records, so SQL Server is attempting to average over all records, but you can't have an aggregate function and provide row details, its one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using old `join` and that's not good `join`. I am advising you to not use it. Read here [*Bad Habits to kick : Using Old Style Joins*](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

```
select 
     p.playerid,NameGiven + ' ( ' + namefirst + ' ) ' + nameLast as [Full Name], 
     teamid, myr,yearid, format(AVG(salary),'C') as [Player Average Salary]
from 
     Salaries s 
     Inner Join People p on  s.playerID=p.playerID 
     Inner Join 
           (select 
                 playerid ,max(yearid) as myr 
            from 
                 Salaries 
            group by 
                 playerID) m on m.playerID=s.playerID
Group By
       P.PlayerID, NameGiven + ' ( ' + namefirst + ' ) ' + nameLast,
       teamid, myr, yearid
```

Your error clear.. Just do `aggregate` with full expression..

Comment: Gladly to help.. And have a nice weekend friend.. :)

Answer (score 1):

firstly, please avoid old style of joining tables. Use `ANSI` style of `JOIN`

on your error, basically whatever column not aggregated, must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. In your case here, you missed the entire `GROUP BY`

```
select 
       p.playerid,
       NameGiven + ' ( ' + namefirst + ' ) ' + nameLast as [Full Name], 
       teamid, 
       myr,
       yearid,
       format(AVG(salary),'C') as [Player Average Salary]    
from       Salaries s
inner join people p    on s.playerID = p.playerID
inner join (
               select playerid ,max(yearid) as myr 
               from   Salaries 
               group by playerID
            ) m        on m.playerID = s.playerID
group by
       p.playerid,
       NameGiven + ' ( ' + namefirst + ' ) ' + nameLast, 
       teamid, 
       myr,
       yearid
```

Answer (score 0):

To show details AND aggregated values over these details, you could use *window functions*. Assuming that you are looking for the average salary of the inspected player (like you did with the `myr`), this would be:

```
SELECT
  p.playerid,
  NameGiven + ' ( ' + namefirst + ' ) ' + nameLast AS [Full Name],
  teamid,
  MAX(yearid) OVER (PARTITION BY p.playerid) AS myr,
  yearid,
  AVG(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY p.playerid) AS [Player Average Salary]
FROM Salaries s
  INNER JOIN people p ON s.playerID = p.playerID;
```

Formatting should be done in the client application or report that consumes the records.